# property not set on runtime in javascript class

Tags: javascript

This is my first time that I try to use javascript to create a class with functions and properties, but I can't understand why in my code the ShowValue function returns the default value and not the one set before the call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $mylocalclass;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $mylocalclass = myclass;
        $mylocalclass.mypropname = "the_name_i_want_here";
    });

    var myclass = (function () {
        var mypropname = "unspecified_name";

        var ShowValue = function () {
            alert(mypropname);
        };

        return {
            ShowValue: ShowValue,
            properties:{
                mypropname: mypropname
            }
        }
    })();
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="$mylocalclass.ShowValue();">Try Me!</button>
```

What I want to do is to use the same class in different pages, but using it differently depending on the name of the local property, which in my case the key for a local storage object. Of course, if I can't set the property from the page, this won't work.

Comment: I do not see a `new` Keyword at all so the function is not working as  a class at all..

Comment: I see an error in the console

Comment: All of the properties are private and you cannot access `mypropname` just like that..

Comment: `mypropname` exists in 3 places.  A local variable, `$mylocalclass.properties.mypropname` (copied from the local variable) and `$mylocalclass.mypropname` (set inside your document ready handler).  They're all very independent of one another.

Comment: Akshay Khandelwal - you are right, I tried to, but it wouldn't work if I would use the 'new' keyword.e.g. $mylocalclass = new myclass(); gives Uncaught TypeError: myclass is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were accessing the private variable `mypropname` within the function. To access the variable you set, use `this`.

Also, you have 3 variables of `mypropname`, 2 of them unused. The

```
var mypropname = "unspecified_name";
```

is simply a private variable that you were using in the `ShowValue` callback and the variable set in the `properties` variable wasn't referenced anywhere else.

Finally, this isn't an instance of an object(or class), but the object itself.

```js
var $mylocalclass;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $mylocalclass = myclass;
        $mylocalclass.properties.mypropname = "the_name_i_want_here";
    });

    var myclass = (function () {
        var mypropname = "unspecified_name";

        var ShowValue = function () {
            alert(this.properties.mypropname);
        };

        return {
            ShowValue: ShowValue,
            properties:{
                mypropname: mypropname
            }
        }
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="$mylocalclass.ShowValue();">Try Me!</button>
```

Comment: This works nicely, but how should I go about this? I want the 'myclass' in an external js file, so I can use it from different place. I would like to use it as a class. i put the variable "mypropname" inside this class / function, so it wouldn't 'pollute' the global variables. Altogether this class will have several methods and properties.